# altura → limits?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

[image]

I looked up "[alturas](https://dle.rae.es/altura)" in DRAE, and none of the definitions seemed to fit this poster.  Is it reasonable to translate this as "There are no limits for a bicycle"?

"There are no heights for …" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It seems like a play on words based on the fact that the brand is Condor (*una bicicleta Condor* = A Condor brand bicycle), which is named after the huge Andean bird that flies higher than any other.

Comment: That didn't occur to me, but still, limits makes more sense than "heights."

Comment: For a translation, sure. I was just shedding some light on the original context based on what I noticed.

Comment: A CONDOR can soar to any height.

Answer (score 3):

There already exists the perfect translation, in my opinion, and you can find it in the very title of the famous song [Ain't no mountain high enough](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t_No_Mountain_High_Enough) written by Ashford & Simpson.

> No hay **alturas** para una bicicleta BH-CONDOR

can be translated as

> Ain't no **mountain high enough** for a BH-CONDOR bike

**Límite (limit, in English) is not a synonym of altura** and it does not transmit the relation between cycling and mountains depicted in the image and present in one of the meanings of [altura](https://dle.rae.es/altura) according to the DLE

> 4. f. Cumbre de los montes, collados o lugares altos del campo, o cualquier otro lugar elevado. U. t. en sent. fig.

Comment: This is very clever indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible translation: "No matter the height (of a mountain, hill, etc.), a bike can ride it". By the way, your translation is also correct because a context, an illustration, is given.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a good translation would be:

- There are no limits for a bicycle.

The original can be understood to be equivalent to:

- Nunca es alto para una bicicleta (It's never high for a bicycle).

The adjective "alto" (and the noun "altura") can mark the top of a scale, from low to high. We sometimes use these extreme adjectives to mean that something is "too" + adjective:

- No puedo ir con la bicicleta ahí. Es alto. (I cannot ride the bicycle there. It's (too) high.)

Note: On reading Ángel José Riesgo's answer, I've realized that my answer above would perhaps be more suitable if "altura" were in the singular. If "alturas" means "high lands" ([entry 4 of DLE](https://dle.rae.es/altura?m=form)), then the ad could mean that this bicycle is so good that it doesn't differentiate between a plain and a high land. Therefore, "no hay alturas para una bicicleta (de esta marca)" would mean "for this bike, a mountainous region does not make a difference / does not represent a problem" (because riding there is like riding on a plain).

Comment: It's never high for a bicycle? What about "Ain't no mountain high enough for a biclyce? It's sound pretty catchy. ;-P I don't agree with your use of the word limit, it's not in the original message. "Nunca es alto para una bicicleta" doesn't seem idiomatic to me and it's translation neither.

Comment: @RubioRic Haven't you ever heard things like: "Es alto para mí" to mean "Es demasiado alto para mí" to refer to a place? Similarly, you can say things like that referring to a bicycle.

Comment: I would use "está" instead of "es" in those cases: "Está demasiado alto para mí"

Comment: Height is a permanent, not a temporary condition.

Comment: I disagree. For example, if I use a ladder the relative height of a lamp, the distance between the lamp and me, can change.

Comment: Both "estar" and "ser" can be used. While "estar" expresses a subjective impression, "ser" expresses an objective fact.

Answer (score 1):

I find the "limits" translation pretty awkward, as the word "alturas" doesn't have that meaning, certainly not in European Spanish, and I wouldn't expect a commercial ad to make use of contrived metaphors. I think the sentence sounds weird unless we consider the brand names that follow as a part of the sentence. If we read it as "No hay alturas para una bicicleta B.H.", it makes much more sense. It's still a bit odd because it says "B.H y Cóndor", which I understand as two different brands, so the grammatical version would be "No hay alturas para [las] bicicletas B.H. y Cóndor". Maybe the poster was designed with just one brand in mind and the second one was added later.

Anyway, if my parsing is correct, "No hay alturas para una bicicleta B.H./Cóndor" sounds fine to me, and "alturas" would refer to the "mountain summits" or "climbs" in cycling races. Basically, the poster says that these bikes are so good that no mountain climb is a problem for them, something like "there are no (insurmountable) climbs for BH/Cóndor bycicles". It's the same construction as "en el fútbol francés, no hay rivales para el PSG".

Comment: "límites" would certainly not be a literal translation but would work finely in the context to express the intended meaning and to make the ad effective.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming context by the picture: a guy riding in the high mountains (backend),  means that `there are not heights for a bicycle` as simple as that, even checking definitions on RAE, I based this on a tracking research of the cartel of Zaragoza España for Behistegui Hermanos Bikes of 1940 add plaque on wikipedia and huncth on my dad's hobby on sport of ciclyn in Spain, also mother tongue is spanish.

[check the source here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beistegui_Hermanos)

Comment: Your proposed translation is not really idiomatic English. Do you mean something like No height is too high for a bicycle?

Comment: well, don't mean to lie it or not,  but in principle is to keep it simple is like saying ``` there is not a challenge that cannot be beaten by this bike```